# Run migration with unique and concurrently in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Just want to confirm, is this how you would label a migration to run a unique constraint and concurrently (active record 4+)

```
disable_ddl_transaction!

def change 
  add_index :strings, [:word, :user_id], unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link you may get some idea about it https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-create-postgres-indexes-concurrently-in